# list of jpeg files in nested subdirectories

Tags: python

I use the following python code to get list of jpg files in nested subdirectories which are in parent directory.

```
import glob2,os    
all_header_files = glob2.glob(os.path.join('Path/to/parent/directory','/**/*.jpg'))
```

However, I get nothing but when I cd into the parent directory and I use the following python code then I get the list of jpeg files.

```
import glob2 
all_header_files = glob2.glob('./**/*.jpg')
```

How can I get the result with the absolute path?(first version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra slash.

The `os.path.join` will *insert* the filepath separators for you, so you should think of it as this to get the correct directory

```
join('Path/to/parent directory' , '**/*.jpg')
```

Even more accurately,

```
parent = os.path.join('Path', 'to', 'parent directory')
os.path.join(parent, '**/*.jpg')
```

If you are trying to use your Home directory, see `os.path.expanduser`

```
In [10]: import os, glob

In [11]: glob.glob(os.path.join('~', 'Downloads', "**/*.sh"))
Out[11]: []

In [12]: glob.glob(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', 'Downloads', "**/*.sh")))
Out[12]:
['/Users/name/Downloads/dir/script.sh']
```

Comment: I used this method but I get nothing yet

Comment: `Path/to/directory` is still a relative path

Comment: No it is not because it is ~/downloads/NewFolder

Comment: Still no output with glob.glob(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', 'Downloads/NewFolder', " ** / *.jpg")))

Comment: Well, then I think you just don't have images there.. I showed you output on my Python 2.7 install

Comment: My python is 3.6 and I have images because second version gives me result. Thanks anyway

Comment: You should verify that `os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', 'Downloads/NewFolder'))` is printing the correct absolute path

Comment: Yes, it prints the absolute path but the problem is that glob.glob(os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads/NewFolder/**/*.jpg')) returns nothing.

Comment: What folders are in-between Downloads and your images?

Comment: jpg files are in nested subdirectories which are in NewFolder directory

Comment: @hsn15051 What was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code you have posted lies in the use of `os.path.join`. 
In the documentation it says for `os.path.join(path, *paths)`:

*If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.*

In your case, the component `/**/*.jpg` is an absolute path, as it starts with a `/`. Consequently your initial input `/Path/to/parent directory` is being truncated by the call to the join function. (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

I have locally tested the joining part with `python3` and for me it is the case, that using `os.path.join(any_path, "/**/*.pdf")` returns the string `'/**/*.pdf'`.

The fix for this error is:

```
import glob2,os    
all_header_files = glob2.glob(os.path.join('Path/to/parent directory','**/*.jpg'))
```

This returns the path `'Path/to/parent directory/**/*.jpg'`

Comment: This is a comment not an answer to the actual question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's the same solution as the other posts. Just doesn't explicitly say it

Comment: @hsn15051 Can you please update the question with what exactly did not work, respectively what the following prints for you: `os.path.join('Path/to/parent directory','**/*.jpg')` ?

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the suggestion, I clarified it.

Answer (score 0):

os.path.join() joins paths in an intelligent way.

```
os.path.join('Path/to/anything','/**/*.jpg'))
```

resolves to `'/**/*.jpg'` since `'/**/*.jpg'` is any path, ever.

Change the `'/**/*.jpg'` to `'**/*.jpg'` and it should work.

In cases like this, I recommend to always try out the result of a certain function within the python command line. At least, this is how I found out the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You should not join with the trailing slash as you'll end up with the root. You can debug by printing out the resulting path before passing it to glob.

Try to change your code like this (note the dot):

```
import glob2,os    
all_header_files = glob2.glob(os.path.join('Path/to/parent directory','./**/*.jpg'))
```

Comment: What exactly didn't work for you? Did you try printing the resulting path?

Comment: Yes, but it does not print anything.

Comment: Please show the exact command that is not working so that we can help